# Cancelling arbitary jobs running in a thread_pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, pthreads, cancellation

Is there a way for a thread-pool to cancel a task underway? Better yet, is there a safe alternative for on-demand cancelling opaque function calls in thread_pools?

Killing the entire process is a bad idea and using native handle to perform `pthread_cancel` or similar API is a last resort only.

### Extra

Bonus if the cancellation is immediate, but it's acceptable if the cancellation has some time constraint 'guarantees' (say cancellation within 0.1 execution seconds of the thread in question for example)

### More details

I am not restricted to using `Boost.Thread.thread_pool` or any specific library. The only limitation is compatibility with C++14, and ability to work on at least BSD and Linux based OS.

The tasks are usually data-processing related, pre-compiled and loaded dynamically using C-API (`extern "C"`) and thus are opaque entities. The aim is to perform compute intensive tasks with an option to cancel them when the user sends interrupts.

While launching, the thread_id for a specific task is known, and thus some API can be sued to find more details if required.

#### Disclaimer

I know using native thread handles to cancel/exit threads is not recommended and is a sign of bad design. I also can't modify the functions using `boost::this_thread::interrupt_point`, but can wrap them in lambdas/other constructs if that helps. I feel like this is a rock and hard place situation, so alternate suggestions are welcome, but they need to be minimally intrusive in existing functionality, and can be dramatic in their scope for the feature-set being discussed.

EDIT:

### Clarification

I guess  this should have gone in the 'More Details' section, but I want it to remain separate to show that existing 2 answers are based o limited information. After reading the answers, I went back to the drawing board and came up with the following "constraints" since the question I posed was overly generic. If I should post a new question, please let me know.

My interface promises a "const" input (functional programming style non-mutable input) by using mutexes/copy-by-value as needed and passing by `const&` (and expecting thread to behave well).

I also mis-used the term "arbitrary" since the jobs aren't arbitrary (empirically speaking) and have the following constraints:

- some which download from "internet" already use a "condition variable"
- not violate const correctness
- can spawn other threads, but they must not outlast the parent
- can use mutex, but those can't exist outside the function body
- output is via `atomic<shared_ptr>` passed as argument
- pure functions (no shared state with outside) **
- ** can be lambda binding a functor, in which case the function needs to makes sure it's data structures aren't corrupted (which is the case as usually, the state is a 1 or 2 `atomic<inbuilt-type>`). Usually the internal state is queried from an external db (similar architecture like cookie + web-server, and the tab/browser can be closed anytime)

These constraints aren't written down as a contract or anything, but rather I generalized based on the "modules" currently in use. The jobs are arbitrary in terms of what they can do: GPU/CPU/internet all are fair play.

It is infeasible to insert a periodic check because of heavy library usage. The libraries (not owned by us) haven't been designed to periodically check a condition variable since it'd incur a performance penalty for the general case and rewriting the libraries is not possible.

Comment: I think "arbitrary" is going to be the death of what you want. You're right. You don't want to kill a thread, but if you can't tell your arbitrary task to exit and expect it to respect the request and exit, you're pretty much screwed and will have to decide: Let it run or drop a guillotine blade on it.

Comment: Oh, I can kill the thread if it cleans up memory resources. The tasks are guaranteed to hold only memory and mutexes, never non-memory resources (like files). The issue is that killing the thread can call std::terminate if done wrong

Comment: @KunalTyagi, killing a thread without killing the whole process is *not* guaranteed to clean up memory resources, nor to treat pthreads synchronization objects such as mutexes in a friendly way.  The only clean way to terminate a thread or to interrupt a pooled task is with the cooperation of the workload -- it must periodically (and in a thread-safe manner) check for and honor a pre-arranged signal that it should terminate early.

Comment: The issue with "periodically checking" is that it's not really possible when there's no loop involved. For anything to do with loops, you could insert a check and preempt the thread. But for compute pipelines, it's only possible at the function boundaries since in real world, it's practically impossible for a function to cooperate unless you write the function youself. Eg: tensorflow, opencv, boost::math none of the big libraries provide ability to preempt because it's expensive to keep checking

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for a thread-pool to cancel a task underway?

Not at that level of generality, no, and also not if the task running in the thread is implemented natively and arbitrarily in C or C++.  You cannot terminate a running task prior to its completion without terminating its whole thread, except with the cooperation of the task.

> Better
>   yet, is there a safe alternative for on-demand cancelling opaque
>   function calls in thread_pools?

No.  The only way to get (approximately) on-demand preemption of a specific thread is to deliver a signal to it (that is is not blocking or ignoring) via `pthread_kill()`. If such a signal terminates the thread but not the whole process then it does not automatically make any provision for freeing allocated objects or managing the state of mutexes or other synchronization objects.  If the signal *does not* terminate the thread then the interruption can produce surprising and unwanted effects in code not designed to accommodate such signal usage.

> Killing the entire process is a bad idea and using native handle to
>   perform pthread_cancel or similar API is a last resort only.

Note that `pthread_cancel()` can be blocked by the thread, and that even when not blocked, its effects may be deferred indefinitely.  When the effects do occur, they do not necessarily include memory or synchronization-object cleanup.  You need the thread to cooperate with its own cancellation to achieve these.

Just what a thread's cooperation with cancellation looks like depends in part on the details of the cancellation mechanism you choose.

Comment: Thanks for your second last paragraph. That helps clear a lot of confusion I had. I was hoping for something similar to erlang's exit/2 which can be used to just up and leave a "process".

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling a non cooperative, not designed to be cancelled component is only possible *if that component has limited, constrained, managed interactions with the rest of the system*:

- the ressources owned by the components should be managed externally (the system knows which component uses what resources)
- all accesses should be indirect
- the modifications of shared ressources should be safe and reversible until completion

That would allow the system to clean up resource, stop operations, cancel incomplete changes...

None of these properties are cheap; **all the properties of threads are the exact opposite of these properties**.

Threads only have an implied concept of ownership apparent in the running thread: for a deleted thread, determining what was owned by the thread is not possible.

Threads access shared objects directly. A thread can start modifications of shared objects; after cancellation, such modifications that would be partial, non effective, incoherent if stopped in the middle of an operation.

Cancelled threads could leave locked mutexes around. **At least** subsequent accesses to these mutexes by **other threads** trying to access the shared object **would deadlock.**

Or they might find some data structure in a bad state.

Providing safe cancellation for arbitrary non cooperative threads is *not doable even with very large scale changes* to thread synchronization objects. Not even by a complete redesign of the thread primitives.

You would have to make thread almost like full processes to be able to do that; but *it wouldn't be called a thread then!*

Comment: So using fork or something similar would help? Is there a library to help in using forks as threads?

Comment: If you switch to processes, you have to rewrite all your code, and even redesign everything, as the data can only be exchanged with inter process communications, like pipes.